# if taxonomy is set show code html - wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, taxonomy

Hi I have a little problem with php/wordpress and can't find answer.

There is a list and one `<li>` I want to show, when anything in custom taxonomy is set:

```
<li class="">Taste: <span><a href="#"><?php printRecipeTaste($post_ID); ?></a></span></li>
```

I have some php in another `<li>` which is working like I want but only for meta:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'iba', true ) ) : ?>
     <img class="iba" src="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>/images/iba.jpg" alt="" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried with get taxonomy_exists and is_taxonomy but I fail.

Anyone can help? Ty.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `get_the_terms($id, $taxonomy)`. Returns false if no terms of that taxonomy are attached to the post.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms